# Best Way to query/visualizate period data (SQL/BI)

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table, business-intelligence, crosstab

lately we have a few cases were I had to build reports where I have one table like:

```
1|text|text
2|text|text
3|text|text
```

and another table

```
1|1.1.2017|text
1|1.2.2017|text
2|1.1.2017|text
2|1.2.2017|text
3|1.1.2017|and so on
```

result should be:

```
            Jan|Feb|March|...
1|text|text|2  | 1 | ...
2|text|text|2  | 1 | ...
3|text|text|1  | 1 | ...
```

My first question would be if there is common way to do this. I already build querys to do this but maybe not so sufficient as they could be. Seems to me as a very common business case so maybe there are (standardized) techniques to do this which I don't know yet.
Another question would be: The queried data would go into a BI tool later. So is it maybe better (faster) to do first the queries, put the tables in BI tools and then manipulate the data as desired? Maybe someone has experience in this and could give me advice...

Thanks

Comment: What is that number against column Jan, Feb, March..... Can you post the query that you have developed?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer to [duplicate ID in sql select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814277/duplicate-id-in-sql-select/47815399#47815399) - except the first sentence.

In my experience it is best to do as you suggested: use SQL to group and aggregate the data as you want and then use a BI tool to present it.

Comment: This link leads to the same page (to **THIS** question/answer). 
A bad link has probably been pasted.

Comment: The link is fixed now.  Sorry for my clumsy copy/paste earlier.